# Convert an array bytes to Mbps PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this php file which i use to get downloaded and uploaded data usage from my splynx radius server over API which outputs it as bytes making a very long string which i want to shorten into Mbps and from the arrays that i get from splynx server i would like help to convert the array "**in_bytes**" and "**out_bytes**" to **MB**. This is my whole code below

```
<?php

$api_url = 'https://xxx/'; // Splynx URL

$admin_login = "xxx"; // administrator login
$admin_password = "xxx"; // administrator password

$api = new SplynxAPI($api_url);
$api->setVersion(SplynxApi::API_VERSION_2);

$isAuthorized = $api->login([
    'auth_type' => SplynxApi::AUTH_TYPE_ADMIN,
    'login' => $admin_login,
    'password' => $admin_password,
]);

if (!$isAuthorized) {
    exit("Authorization failed!\n");
}

$customerApiUrl_online = "admin/customers/customers-online";

$customers_params = [
    'main_attributes' => [
        'status' => ['IN', ['active', 'blocked']]
    ]];

$result_online = $api->api_call_get($customerApiUrl_online);
$customers_online = $api->response;
?>

<table class="table table-transparent">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DOWNOAD</th>
            <th>UPLOAD</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($customers_online as $item) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $item['in_bytes']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['out_bytes']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 8 bits in a byte 1000000 bits in a megabit so megabits = bytes * 8 * 1000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting between them is trivial. It's a simple mathematical operation.

The question is what do you mean by **Mbps** exactly? Do you mean Mega **bits** per second? Or Mega **bytes** per second? There's a significant difference:

```
function bytesToMbps($bytes) {
    $bits = $bytes * 8;
    return sprintf("%.2fMbps", $bits / 1000000); // Mega bits per second
}

echo bytesToMbps(1024*1024*97); // 813.69Mbps
```

Or **MBps**:

```
function bytesToMbps($bytes) {
    return sprintf("%.2fMbps", $bytes / 1024 / 1024); // Mega bytes per second
}

echo bytesToMbps(1024*1024*97); // 97.00Mbps
```

More importantly are you **only** interested in conversion of bytes to Mbps or do you want a general logarithmic conversion function?

```
function bytesLog($bytes) {
    $magnitudes = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB"];
    $mag = log($bytes, 1024);

    return sprintf("%.2f%s", $bytes / (1024 ** ((int) $mag)), $magnitudes[(int)$mag]);
}

echo bytesLog(1023); // 1023.00B -- Bytes
echo bytesLog(1024*3); // 3.00KB -- Kilobytes
echo bytesLog(1024*1024*12); // 12.00MB -- Megabytes
echo bytesLog(1024*1024*1024*134); // 134.00GB -- Gigabytes
echo bytesLog(1024*1024*1024*1024*768); // 768.00TB -- Terabytes
echo bytesLog(1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*960); // 960.00PB -- Petabytes
echo bytesLog(1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*512); // 512.00EB -- Exabytes
```

Comment: I actually made a mistake its suppose to be just MB and not Mbp. Thank you for correcting me. Can you also show me on the complete code how it should be

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly got it to work using the following to MB

```
<?php echo round(floatval($item['in_bytes'])/1000000,2); ?>
```